# jQuery Cycle full width wrapper on each slide

Tags: jquery, html, css, cycle

I am using jQuery Cycle for a slide show with a styled image for the background in the main content area. I am fading that image to a solid color. The solid color will span the full width of the page. The colors are written dynamically in a CMS. The CMS adds the class name of the color to the container (li) that Cycle affects. Cycle resets all of my layout? Has anyone done this before?

This is how I want the styling to look (without Cycle):
http://riverdistrictstudio.com/slider/index-no-cycle.html

With Cycle:
http://riverdistrictstudio.com/slider/

Comment: I found a JS solution: http://www.yelotofu.com/2011/06/jquery-cycle-and-fullscreen/ -- A CSS solution would be better, but maybe it is not possible.

Comment: I think the reason is that cycle sets your `li` elements to `position: absolute` which makes them shrink wrap. You need to explicitly set the width to 100%.

Answer (score 0):

The Cycle plugin contrains the slides to their smallest size and makes them absolute so it can fade them in through each other.

The way you can still make it span the entire width would be to wrap a `div` arround the `ul` and style that, make it `width: 100%;` and give the ul `margin: 0 auto;` to center it in the div.

Comment: Centering is not the problem. The problem is that the background color of the full-width wrappers need to animate the same time as the fixed-width content width the styled bg image.

Comment: In that case you need to modify the Cycle plugin so it doesn't force height and widths. Or use another plugin or write it yourself, a fade transition is the easiest arround. [Here is mine](http://jsfiddle.net/RFJMy/222/) and I wrote it specifically for this reason, no extra positioning or forcing dimensions.